# PyQt ToolTip for QTreeView

Tags: pyqt, tooltip, qtreeview

Please axplain how to enable and show a tooltip for each item in QTreeView. I found a sample of code `class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel)` but due to my beginner's level I can't understand how to apply it to my needs.

Data for tooltip should be taken from value of key "note" in dictionary `data_for_tree`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

data_for_tree = {"tomato":{"color":"red","ammount":"10", "note":"a note for tomato"},"banana":{"color":"yellow","ammount":"1", "note":"b note for banana"}, "some fruit":{"color":"unknown","ammount":"100", "note":"some text"}}

class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        #...
        if role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            return 'ToolTip'

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags # 0
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable # or Qt.ItemIsEnabled            

class ProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)
        try:
            return float(leftData) < float(rightData)
        except ValueError:
            return leftData < rightData

class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.MyTreeView = QTreeView()
        self.MyTreeViewModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.MyTreeView.setModel(self.MyTreeViewModel)
        self.most_used_cat_header = ['Name', "ammount", "color"]
        self.MyTreeViewModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.most_used_cat_header)
        self.MyTreeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.MyTreeView_Fill()

        MainWindow = QHBoxLayout(self)    
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.MyTreeView)
        self.setLayout(MainWindow)

    def MyTreeView_Fill(self):
        for k in data_for_tree:
            name = QStandardItem(k)
            ammount = QStandardItem(data_for_tree[k]["ammount"])
            note = QStandardItem(data_for_tree[k]["color"])
            tooltip = data_for_tree[k]["note"]
            item = (name, ammount, note)
            self.MyTreeViewModel.appendRow(item)
        self.MyTreeView.sortByColumn(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        proxyModel = ProxyModel(self)
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.MyTreeViewModel)
        self.MyTreeView.setModel(proxyModel)

        c = 0
        while c < len(self.most_used_cat_header):
            self.MyTreeView.resizeColumnToContents(c)
            c=c+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    main.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - main.rect().center())
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the `QStandardItem` and `QStandardItemModel` classes (which is what I would recommend!) you don't need to bother with the `TreeModel` class you have found. Creating your own model is rarely necessary, but for some reason tutorials often encourage you to do so. If you find something encouraging you to subclass `QAbstractItemModel`, I suggest you check on stack overflow first to see if there is a simpler way to do it! In this case, there is a very simple way to add your tooltips.

If you look at the C++ documentation (which I often find more useful than the PyQt documentation for finding out what methods are available), you will see that `QStandardItem` has a method called [`setToolTip()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setToolTip).

So all you need to do is call this method on each of the items you add to the model. For example, inside the loop in the `MyTreeView_Fill` method:

```
name = QStandardItem(k)
ammount = QStandardItem(data_for_tree[k]["ammount"])
note = QStandardItem(data_for_tree[k]["color"])
tooltip = data_for_tree[k]["note"]
name.setToolTip(tooltip)
ammount.setToolTip(tooltip)
note.setToolTip(tooltip)
```

Here I've set the tooltip to be the same for every cell in the row (name, amount and note) but you could easily change this to have a different tooltip for one of the cells (hopefully it is obvious how to do that)

Comment: Thank you. Surely I looked for solution in stackoverflow and I found a setTooltip method, but the reason I asked a question is I tried to apply that method to `item`. In my case `item` is a tuple so there were error message. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @SergiiArtele Ah, I See! Well, glad I could help!